# Filter Google Drive docs that are Shared with Me, but not Moved to My Drive

Tags: google-drive

In Google Drive, is there a way to list only those files which have been Shared with Me, but which I have not Moved to My Drive ? I would like to be able to easily distinguish those files so that I can file them into My Drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search

```
is:unorganized -owner:me
```

appears to do this. Here, `is:unorganized` find the files that do not have a parent folder, and `-owner:me` excludes those you own.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I found is to enter the "Shared with me" folder and change the view mode to "List view".

The icon looks like this: [image: List view icon]

Then, in the very right column you have the name of the My Drive folder or just **empty space** if it is not present in My Drive. I didn't find a way how to really filter them, so this does not answer your question precisely.

*One note more:* Sometimes, I had to refresh the whole page to reflect the changes. Maybe a bug.

Comment: I don't see this column with folder names, did the interface change since you posted this?

Comment: I do not see such a column with parent folder names.  Instead, I see (after selecting a particular file) two things: 1) an icon in the Google Drive "toolbar" area top right portion of the screen: if the file is already in My Drive, the icon is a "folder with arrow" (indicating "Move" operation"); if the file is not yet in My Drive, the icon is "folder with plus" (indicating "Add to My Drive" operation. 2) In the "Info / Details pane on right side of screen, the location field will show if the file is already in My Drive, else the location field will not show. Either way, not a simple list.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the "folder" shown in red in the image (in my case, empty).

[image: WA52998 example]

[For details of what you *won't* find in there](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375057?hl=en).