# What is the search operator to exclude files already added to My Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-search

In Google Drive, I want to find files that I have visibility but are not yet added to My Drive, how can I do that using Advance Search or search operators in the search bar?

There's a similar [question with answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52998/filter-google-drive-docs-that-are-shared-with-me-but-not-moved-to-my-drive) but it doesn't work in 2020?

I am using corporate gsuite.

Comment: Well, `in:root` searches for items in My Drive, but `-in:root` doesn't do the opposite.

Comment: Whenever I search `in:root` it gives error "The server encountered an error. Please try again later"